# How does std:set check if there is an equivalent element in set during the insertion?

Tags: c++, c++14, std, stdset

Let's use the following code as an example.

```
auto cmp = [](ll a, ll b) {
    return gcd(12, a) < gcd(12, b);
};
set<ll, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp);
for(ll i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    ll x;
    cin >> x;
    s.insert(x);
    cout << "Success! \n";
}
```

I defined new comparator that compares numbers by their greatest common divisor with 12.

First I successfully inserted 5. And then I tried to insert 7, but it was not successful.

I know that gcd(12, 5) = gcd(12, 7) = 1.

But I am failing to understand how does `std::set` check if 5 is equivalent to 7.

It can find out that gcd(12, 7) is not less than gcd(12, 5) using comparator *comp* I gave it, but how does it figure out that gcd(12, 7) is equal to gcd(12, 5)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It calls the comparator twice, with different order of arguments.

If `cmp(x, y)` and `cmp(y, x)` are both false, then `x` and `y` are considered to be equivalent.